# Type properties so that they are mutually exclusive

Tags: reactjs, typescript

How should I type my properties, so that either `buttonLink` or `clickHandler`, but not both, could be passed to my component at the same time?

```
export type ConfirmationProps = {
  buttonLink?: string
  clickHandler?: OnClick
}

export const Confirmation: FC<ConfirmationProps> = ({
  buttonLink,
  clickHandler,
}): JSX.Element => {
  return (  
    {clickHandler && (
      <Button onClick={clickHandler}>
        Button
      </Button>
    )}
    {buttonLink && (
      <Link href={buttonLink}>
        Link
      </Link>
    )}
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be achieved by declaring possible variants and using `never` type:

```
export type ConfirmationProps = ({
  buttonLink: string
  clickHandler?: never
} | {
  buttonLink?: never
  clickHandler: OnClick
});
```

For your information, if there are other props which are common and acceptable for both variants then you can use the same solution, but firstly declare the common part and then use the `&` intersection literal:

```
export type ConfirmationProps = {
  commonprop1: number
  commonprop2: number
} & ({
      buttonLink: string
      clickHandler?: never
    } | {
      buttonLink?: never
      clickHandler: OnClick
    });
```

Comment: I get linting errors with the above format

Comment: @Dimoff Which errors? I've checked it on typescript playground and everything is fine there.